# Airflow - Incorrect Last Run

Tags: airflow, airflow-scheduler

I just ran an airflow DAG. When I see the airflow last run date, it displays the last but last run date. It catches my attention when I hover over the "i" icon it shows the correct date. Is there any way to solve this? Sounds like nonsense but I end up using it for QA of my data.

[image]

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is probably because your airflow job has `catchup=True` enabled and a `start_date` in the past, so it is back-filling.

The Start Date is the real-time date of the last run, whereas the Last Run is the execution date of the airflow job. For example, if I am back-filling a time partitioned table with data from 2016-01-01 to present, the Start Date will be the current date but the Last Run date will be 2016-01-01.

Please include your DAG file/code in the future.

Edit: If you don't have `catchUp=True` enabled, and the discrepancy is approximately one day (like in the picture you sent), then that is just due to the behaviour of the scheduler. From the [docs](https://airflow.readthedocs.io/en/stable/scheduler.html), "The scheduler runs your job one schedule_interval AFTER the start date, at the END of the period."

if you run a DAG on a `schedule_interval` of one day, the run stamped 2016-01-01 will be triggered soon after 2016-01-01T23:59. In other words, the job instance is started once the period it covers has ended.

Comment: I have the same issue, however in my case the catchup is set to False.

Comment: Is the discrepancy just one day, or several? If just one day, read the [documentation](https://airflow.readthedocs.io/en/stable/scheduler.html) on scheduling: "The scheduler runs your job one schedule_interval AFTER the start date, at the END of the period."

Comment: the link above no longer works